# How to get the entire skb data content instead of the address in eBPF/libbpf?

Tags: kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf, skb

I'm writing code in `libbpf` to get the entire data packet content (not address) by funtion `bpf_probe_read_kernel`.

For example, `bpf_probe_read_kernel(my_struct, 512, skb->data);`

But there's an error: `invalid mem access 'inv'` which probably tells me that I don't have access directly to `skb->data`.

But if I add an `&` before, let's say `bpf_probe_read_kernel(my_struct, 512, &skb->data);`, there's no error but I can only get the address which is not what I want.

So any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Please share the code example.

Answer (score 0):

First, not all program types have access to the entire skb data content. For example, the `BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SKB` can only access the data header (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455418/7776212)).

Secondly, if in case you are using a supported hook, e.g. `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SK_SKB`, then also it might be possible that the socket data is non-linear, due to the scatter-gather structure of skbuffs. In this case, you need to first 'pull' the socket data together using the `bpf_skb_pull_data()` helper. Check the man page [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html#:%7E:text=of%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20failure.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20long-,bpf_skb_pull_data,-(struct%20sk_buff%20*).